# numpy vectorize np.prod Cannot construct a ufunc with more than 32 operands

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I know there is a similar question here: [Python numpy.vectorize: ValueError: Cannot construct a ufunc with more than 32 operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090956/python-numpy-vectorize-valueerror-cannot-construct-a-ufunc-with-more-than-32-o/63093878#63093878)

But my case is different.

I have a df with 32 columns ,you can have it by running following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
dfs = """
    M0  M1  M2  M3 M4  M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M13 M14 M15 M16 M17 M18 M19 M20 M21 M22 M23 M24 M25 M26 M27 M28 M29 M30  age 
1   1   2   3    4  5   6  1  2 3    4  5  6   1   2    3  4  5    6   7   8    9 1    2  3    4  5    6  1    2   3    4   3.2        
2   7   5   4    5  8   3  1  2 3    4  5  6   1   2    3  4  5    6   7   8    9 1    2  3    4  5    6  1    2   3    4   4.5
3   4   8   9    3  5   2  1  2 3    4  5  6   1   2    3  4  5    6   7   8    9 1    2  3    4  5    6  1    2   3    4   6.7
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfs.strip()), sep='\s+', )
df
```

based on business logic I built a vectorized function, and if the total number of the parameters of function is **less than 32** it works fine:

```
M=["M0","M1","M2","M3","M4","M5","M6","M7","M8","M9","M10","M11","M12","M13","M14","M15","M16","M17","M18","M19",
       "M20","M21","M22","M23","M24","M25","M26","M27","M28","M29"]
    
    def func2(df, M):
        return [df[i].values for i in M] 
    
    def func(age,*Ms):
        newcol=np.prod(Ms[0:age])
        return newcol
    
    vfunc = np.frompyfunc(func, len(M)+1, 1)
    
    df['newcol']=vfunc(df['age'].values.astype(int), *func2(df,M))
```

For easy understanding,func2 is just make the code more clean,it generates all the parameters for func,without func2 the code will looks like:

```
def func(age,M0,M1,M2,...,M29):
    newcol=np.prod(Ms[0:age])
    return newcol

vfunc = np.frompyfunc(func, 31, 1)

df['newcol']=vfunc(df['age'].values.astype(int), df['M1'].values,...,df['M29'].values)
```

The real problem is once the number of parameters is **equal or larger than 32** like this:

```
M=["M0","M1","M2","M3","M4","M5","M6","M7","M8","M9","M10","M11","M12","M13","M14","M15","M16","M17","M18","M19",
           "M20","M21","M22","M23","M24","M25","M26","M27","M28","M29","M30"] # M30 is the only difference from the above function
        
        def func2(df, M):
            return [df[i].values for i in M] 
        
        def func(age,*Ms):
            newcol=np.prod(Ms[0:age])
            return newcol
        
        vfunc = np.frompyfunc(func, len(M)+1, 1)
        
        df['newcol']=vfunc(df['age'].values.astype(int), *func2(df,M))
```

I received error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-9a042ad44f9b> in <module>()
     76     return newcol
     77 
---> 78 vfunc = np.frompyfunc(func, len(M)+1, 1)
     79 
     80 df['newcol']=vfunc(df['age'].values.astype(int), *func2(df,M))

ValueError: Cannot construct a ufunc with more than 32 operands (requested number were: inputs = 32 and outputs = 1)
```

In my real business logic I have more than 100 columns need use np.pro to calculate, so this really stuck me. Any friend can help?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093878/12664040) may answer your question?

Comment: Full traceback please!

Comment: Updated my question and pated full traceback.

Comment: @jezza_99 no,thank you for your reply.

Comment: Sorry, what is your end goal? Do you mind posting the expected output dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code. But why `np.vectorize`? Cant you not do `df[M].prod(axis=1)`? Or even something like a `for` loop?

Comment: note that `np.vectorize` does not make your function "vectorized" in the sense you're probably referring to - np.vectorize is a convenience function that essentially runs a for loop over the array elements. The vectorized solution you seem to be trying to achive should use pandas operations such as df.prod as suggested by @QuangHoang

Comment: @Ben.T Thank you for your reply ,can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @QuangHoang since I need apply the logic to each row,and if I use pd.apply() it will be very slow,so I need use numpy,can you post your reply as an answer ,thank you so much

Comment: @William my point is `np.vectorize` is not faster than either `pd.apply` or a `for` loop. As for solution, @Ben.T's comment is perfect for your case (sans some corner cases). I did not see his comment when I put down my first one.

Comment: As I explained in the linked SO, you cannot use `frompyfunc` (or `np.vectorize`) with a large number of arguments.  This 32 limit is the max number of dimensions of an array.  Most likely you are using it wrong, for something it wasn't designed for, and where it has **no** speed benefits.

Comment: @QuangHoang, apparently last year I found that `np.vectorize` is faster than pandas `apply` or row iterate.But that's because pandas is so slow with all of its indexing baggage.  I didn't test `apply` with its `raw` mode which bypasses a lot of that.

Comment: How is it different from what Ben proposed in his answer here?

Comment: @QuangHoang it not work, received errors ,my new question just make my question more straightforward hopefully ,thank you very much for your reply

Comment: I suggest you be more specific than *it not work*. What is the error? Does it give different output than what you expect (where, and why the difference)?

Comment: @QuangHoang I updated my pandas version ,it works now!Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve your result. Select all the M columns with `filter`, use `where` to replace by nan all the values that the column position is higher than the age column, then `prod` along the columns.

```
df['newcol'] = (
     # keep only Mx columns
    df.filter(like='M')
      # keep only the values when the position of the column
      # is less than the age
      .where(lambda x: (np.arange(x.shape[1])+1)<df['age'].to_numpy()[:, None])
      # multiply all the non-nan values per row
      .prod(axis=1)
)
print(df)
```

Comment: @QuangHoang after updated my pandas version it works now,thanks!

Comment: What if instead of using MO ...M30,I need use 1-M0..1-M30 ?I tried 1-(np.arange(x.shape[1])+1) and (np.arange(1-x.shape[1])+1),but receives errors

Comment: @William if you mean the name of the columns starts with 1-M? then in the filter the parameter `like='1-M'` should select the columns

Comment: Thank you for your reply not the name is the values should be 1-df['M0]...1-df['M30'],sorry for the confuse

Comment: So in your answer we are using the value of df['M0']...df['M30'] to do calculation ,what if we need use the value of 1-df['M0']..1-df['M30'] ?

Comment: @William maybe you can do `(1 - df.filter(like='M')).where(...` the rest the same

Comment: it works really appreciate